# why Pi is transcendental number if it will satisfy the algebraic equation as "n" tends to infinity?

Tags: pi, transcendental-numbers

why Pi is transcendental number if $\pi$ also have algebraic equation like below  which have root at  $x =\pi/3$   as $n$ tends to infinity.
$$\Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl((x^2-2^{(n2^1+1)})^2-2^{(n2^2+1)}\bigr)^2-2^{(n2^3+1)}\Bigr)^2...-2^{(n2^{(n-1)}+1)}\biggr)^2-2^{n2^{n}+1}\Biggr)^2 = 3*2^{n2^{(n+1)}}$$

For $n = 1$ equation will be $$(x^2-2^3)^2 = 3*2^4$$
and its root  $x_1$ = 1.03527618041.

For $n = 2$ equation will be $$((x^2-2^5)^2-2^9)^2 = 3*2^{16}$$
and its root is $x_2$ =  1.04420953776041 
and as we increase the value of n the root tends to $\pi/3$.

For n  = 12 ,$3x_{12}$ will be  3.14159264 which is some what close to $\pi$.

Another simplified version of this equation is $${\Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl(\frac{\pi}{3*2^n}\bigr)^2-2\Bigr)^2-2\biggr)^2...-2\Biggr)^2} = 3$$
Here n is the same as number of single powered two in above equation.

Solution of the above equation will be $$\pi = 3*\Biggl(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+....\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}}}\Biggr)*2^n$$
and $$n =\text{ number  of $2$ inside  largest  square  root}$$
So if $\pi$ can also be represented as a root of algebraic equation then why $\pi$ is transcendental .

Comment: Every real number is the limit of a sequence of rational numbers, and every rational number is algebraic.

Comment: A number is algebraic if it is a root of a polynomial equation of *finite* degree with integer coefficients. None of the equations you have presented is such.

Comment: A convergent sequence of algebraic numbers need not tend to an algebraic number, such as a convergent sequence of rational numbers need not tend to a rational number.

Answer (score 6):

Algebra for the most part is not concerned with sequences and limits. A real or complex number is said to be algebraic if it is a root of a single polynomial equation of finite degree with integer coefficients. This is something that $\pi$ is not.

If you are willing to use limits, then every number is "algebraic" : you can always find a sequence of polynomial equations with integer coefficients whose roots converge to any number. For real numbers, the polynomials can even be linear! So in a sense this is not interesting. The specific equations you outline are interesting, but the conclusion is not as it is true for any number.

Comment: Can you add any case of e bring transcendental under limits? I think it'll reaffirm the statement you made.

Answer (score 4):

All you've shown is that $\pi$ can be **approximated by** algebraic numbers. But that's not the same as **being** an algebraic number! When you write

> $\pi$ can also be represented as a root of algebraic equation

you're misusing the term "algebraic equation." There is a sense in which $\pi$ can be thought of as the solution to an "infinite algebraic equation," but that's not the same thing.

Indeed, the same reasoning would also imply that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational since we can get better and better rational approximations to it (this is expanding on Rijul Saini's comment above). Or that the infinite sum $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 1=1+1+1+1+ ...$ is finite since for each $n$, the partial sum $\sum_{i=1}^n1$ is finite.

In general, **you cannot conflate finite objects with their infinite analogues**.

---

This is not to say that there's nothing interesting here. While every real number is "limit algebraic," things get more interesting when we look at *functions* - thinking about "infinite-degree polynomials" leads to the concept of [analytic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function), which is absolutely fundamental. But that's a separate issue.

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_1_%2B_1_%2B_1_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) that in a sense $1+1+1+1+\cdots = \zeta(0)=-\frac12$ which looks like a finite algebraic number to me

Comment: @Henry Sigh, really? That statement is misleading shorthand for a more complicated technical fact which in no way contradicts the divergence of the sum in the actual sense. Bringing this up will only confuse the OP.

Comment: @NoahSchweber OK I understand what you are saying that this equations are algebraic for any finite value of $n$ but $\pi$ will be solution only if n tends to infinity.But If we look at final value of $\pi$ which i mentioned above is in the form $\sqrt{(2-k)}*3*2^n$. And as n tends to infinity k will tend to 2 so it will became $0*\infty$ Form .So is there any way to simplify it.

Comment: @abhishekgayari I don't understand what you're asking. You're playing too fast and loose with limits at the moment. What sort of thing are you hoping for (that is, what does "is there any way to simplify it" mean)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber

$\pi = 3*\Biggl(\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+....\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}}}\Biggr)*2^n$
and $k = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+....\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}}}}$    

so $\pi = 3*\sqrt{2-k}*2^n$ and as $n$ tends to $\infty $ ,$k$ tends to $2$ then $\pi$ will tend to $3*0*\infty $ 

So I'm Asking that could this  $\pi$ be in more simplified form or can this $n$ be eliminated.